# How to make only one integer can be written in the box?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make only 1 number can be written in the box (maximum is number 8). Is there anyway to do that?

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="seal_qty">Seal Quantity:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="seal_qty" name="seal_qty" min="1" max="8" placeholder="Enter Seal Quantity" value="<?php echo $seal_qty; ?>">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10"></div>

var seal_qty = document.translot.seal_qty.value;
    if (seal_qty == null || seal_qty ==""){
        alert("Seal Quantity should not be blank.");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain it more clear? 1 number? Is it a single digit number only from 1 to 8?

Comment: @SurajSanwal yes only single digit like 1,2,3. Maximum is up to 8 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). Like that. If more than 8 (let's say, I insert as 9, show alert "maximum is 8.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `lenght` and number like:

```js
const seal_qty = document.querySelector('#seal_qty');
seal_qty.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  const value = parseInt(input.value);
  if(value.length > 1 || value > 8){
    input.value = '';
    alert("maximum is 8.");
  }
});
```

```html
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="seal_qty">Seal Quantity:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">    
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="seal_qty" name="seal_qty" min="1" max="8" placeholder="Enter Seal Quantity">
    
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10"></div>
```

Comment: Should I put under "var seal_qty = document.translot.seal_qty.value" or where should I put the script?

Comment: What is translot ? use my code `const seal_qty = document.querySelector('#seal_qty');`

Comment: translot is my jsfile name. It's translot.js.

Comment: Oh yes put into the file and include it into html.